# Why does this binary classification accuracy calculation work?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I have began to play around with Keras, and have noticed that many of the examples do not use the built in Keras accuracy metrics but rather their own accuracy function which they run the `y_pred` values through in relation to `y_true`.

The function is used for computing the accuracy of binary classification [0,1] but I do not understand why it works, as even on a small example I can see it is incorrect.

The function in the Keras example code is:

```
def compute_accuracy(predictions, labels):
    return labels[predictions.ravel()<0.5].mean()
```

However, if we use the example of

```
labels = [0,1,1,1]
predictions = [0.2, 0.6, 0.7, 0.3]
```

we can see that the classifier only got one of the predictions incorrect (0.3 was labelled as 1 instead of 0). However in this case the above accuracy function says that the accuracy is 0.5 and not 0.75. Furthermore, if using the binary accuracy metric within Keras, I get completely different accuracy results. I think I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: What accuracy you've got?

Comment: On my training set this accuracy function gives +-98% while the Keras binary function gives about 2%. That is with the MNIST dataset and a siamese model given with Keras